# Unexpected display for RadioButton on CheckAlign = TopCenter

Tags: c#, alignment, flowlayoutpanel

I need to add some `RadioButton`s to a `FlowLayoutPanel`.

If I leave radio buttons' properties as default, it will fine. But if I set `CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter`, it will go wrong, like this

[image: Wrong display on flow layout panel]

Here's my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    RadioButton opt = new RadioButton() {
        Text = "Test",
        CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter
    };

    pnlPassNumbers.Controls.Add(opt);
}
```

Anybody know how was it wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't describe actually what is the wrong part.  That is, should the text be aligned to the left of the mark, or below it?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    RadioButton opt = new RadioButton() {
        Text = "Test",
        CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter,
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter.
        Size = new Size(86, 36)
    };

    pnlPassNumbers.Controls.Add(opt);
}
```

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. My experience with "touching" the CheckAlign and TextAlign properties has usually never ended well.  Creating the RadioButtons outside of the designer though, I either have to set the Size, or set the AutoSize=true again (despite being the default) on my machine because the text gets cut off on the bottom.  Odd properties.